# nuxt (2) layout > mounted() not being called

Tags: nuxt.js

Is the mounted() method supposed to be called in layout file's default export() section?

I've done some testing and mounted() doesn't seem to be getting called (in neither default.vue nor error.vue layout files).

I've googled this but can't seem to find anything on it (which may mean it's not supposed to work)

Error template, according to [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views/#error-page)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 v-if="error.statusCode === 404">Page not found</h1>
        <h1 v-else>An error occurred</h1>

        <p>error.statusCode=</p>
        {{ error.statusCode }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: [
        'error'
    ],

    //layout: 'error', // you can set a custom layout for the error page

    // not being called :(
    mounted() {
        console.log('beforeMount!');
        console.log(this.error.statusCode);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was chrome issue. Loaded page in Firefox and worked just fine.